# onLocationChanged() method is not getting called

Tags: java, android, xml

I'm trying to find the location of my device using `LocationManager`; the `onLocationChanged()` method is not getting called no matter what i try (tried changing the location using mock location app, tried switching off and on the phone I'm trying to run the app on etc). Here's my code and the logcat:

```
LocationManager mlocationManager;
LocationListener mlocationListener;
long MIN_TIME = 5000;
float MIN_DISTANCE = 1000;
final int COARSE_LOCATION_REQUEST_CODE=102;
String LOCATION_PROVIDER = LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER;
```

## My onResume() method:

```
 @Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    Log.d("ClimateControl", "onResume was called");
   getWeatherForCurrentLocation();
}
```

## My getWeatherForCurrentLocation() method:

```
 private void getWeatherForCurrentLocation() {

    mlocationManager = (LocationManager) this.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    mlocationListener = new LocationListener() {
        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
            Log.d("ClimateControl", "onLocationChanged() has been called");
            String longitude = String.valueOf(location.getLongitude());
            String latitude = String.valueOf(location.getLatitude());
            Log.d("ClimateControl", "Latitude: " + latitude + "Longitude: " + longitude);
        }

        @Override
        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
            Log.d("ClimateControl", "onStatusChanged() has been called");

        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
            Log.d("ClimateControl", "onProviderEnabled() has been called");


        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
            Log.d("ClimateControl", "onProviderDisabled() has been called");

        }
    };
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        // TODO: Consider calling
        //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
        // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
        //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
        //                                          int[] grantResults)
        // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
        // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION},COARSE_LOCATION_REQUEST_CODE);
    }
    mlocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LOCATION_PROVIDER,MIN_TIME,MIN_DISTANCE,mlocationListener);

}
```

## My onRequestPermissionsResult() method:

```
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);

    if(requestCode == COARSE_LOCATION_REQUEST_CODE){
        if(grantResults.length>0 && grantResults[0]==PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
            Log.d("ClimateControl","Request granted");
            getWeatherForCurrentLocation();
        }
        else{
            Log.d("ClimateControl","Request denied");
        }
    }

}
```

## My logcat regarding ClimateControl tag:

```
08-06 22:09:42.949 29359-29359/com.example.praty.climatecontrol D/ClimateControl: onResume was called
```

SideNote: I did try adding another `requestLocationUpdates()` implementation with the String provider as `LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER` but there was a fatal error making my app crash

PS: My complete debug logcat:

```
    08-07 16:59:35.229 9417-9417/? I/art: Late-enabling -Xcheck:jni
    08-07 16:59:35.388 9417-9417/? W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/com.example.praty.climatecontrol-1/lib/arm64
    08-07 16:59:35.449 9417-9417/com.example.praty.climatecontrol W/art: Before Android 4.1, method android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter android.support.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawableCompat.updateTintFilter(android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter, android.content.res.ColorStateList, android.graphics.PorterDuff$Mode) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in android.graphics.drawable.Drawable
    08-07 16:59:35.812 9417-9417/com.example.praty.climatecontrol D/ClimateControl: onResume was called
    08-07 16:59:35.861 9417-9486/com.example.praty.climatecontrol I/Adreno: QUALCOMM build                   : bc01238, I8e5c908169
Build Date                       : 12/06/16
OpenGL ES Shader Compiler Version: XE031.09.00.03
Local Branch                     : 
Remote Branch                    : quic/LA.BR.1.3.6_rb1.10
Remote Branch                    : NONE
Reconstruct Branch               : NOTHING
    08-07 16:59:35.900 9417-9486/com.example.praty.climatecontrol I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
    08-07 16:59:35.900 9417-9486/com.example.praty.climatecontrol D/OpenGLRenderer: Swap behavior 1
    08-07 16:59:36.581 9417-9417/com.example.praty.climatecontrol E/SpannableStringBuilder: SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length
SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length
    08-07 16:59:38.171 9417-9417/com.example.praty.climatecontrol D/ClimateControl: onResume was called
```

Comment: I hope you have declared permissions in manifest file. I have used your code and verified it is working . I got this log message `D/ClimateControl: onLocationChanged()` has been called

Comment: Yeah, the permissions have been declared: <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>

Comment: See the answer below, it should solve your issue now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why `onLocationChanged` is not getting called because you have not declared permission `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>`.

Try adding missing permission in your manifest file and then retest. It should be working fine.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue I see where you call the `requestLocationUpdates` method.

Take it out from `getWeatherForCurrentLocation` method and Call it when you see permission granted for permissions in `onRequestPermissionsResult`.

Ofcourse, Make sure that you have 3 permissions mentioned in manifest of `android.permission.INTERNET, android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION and android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION`

```
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] 
                                         permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);

if(requestCode == COARSE_LOCATION_REQUEST_CODE){
    if(grantResults.length>0 && grantResults[0]==PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
        Log.d("ClimateControl","Request granted");

        //here you know you have permission and then u can ask location updates, this will trigger locationListener methods on respective time you mentioned with below parameters. 

        mlocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LOCATION_PROVIDER,MIN_TIME,MIN_DISTANCE,mlocationListener);

    }
    else{
        Log.d("ClimateControl","Request denied");
    }
  }

}
```

Hope it helps.. !!

Comment: Seems like i can't add the requestLocationUpdates() call under the if statement; the compiler is showing an error (wants me to add another checkPermission block of code)

Comment: Also, I hadn't added the ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION permission in the manifest file before, but now I have and the method is still not getting called

Comment: It says you have to make sure to ask the permission, but you already did that and you are in the block which granted the permission so, That is fine, take help of compiler itself, you can add the if above it using alt+tab, moreover, even if you dont add that "if" its going to work just fine, program will run and you will see desired result.

Comment: Okay so I did what you said but the method is still not getting called

Comment: Are you sure you have GPS on or internet on? If not, please keep GPS and internet on, and for your location provider keep it to LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, as it will give you more accurate position.

Comment: glad it is solved, if my answer helped, please mark it as answer.